# Retrieving integer values from LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, sum

Can anyone help me for below situation?

```
List ll = new LinkedList();
ll.add(10);
ll.add(20);
ll.add("king");
ll.add(30);
ll.add(40);
```

I want the sum of all above integers in list.

Comment: king is not an integer, use generics.

Comment: The fact you ask this question is probably caused by the fact that your design is bad.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I *highly* recommend a beginner's book on Java, or at the very least starting wit the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over the list and for each element check if it's an integer or not:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Object o : ll) {
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        sum += ((Integer)o).intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, sure .. this works because of legacy support, but it's incredibly *bad* to do so. So much so that this is a really **terrible** answer.

Comment: Yes its working..thank you but should we use "instanceof" definitely?

Comment: @user2173142 No. Your example code is quite frankly, notihng that should ever happen; you're mixing random types in a raw List. This answer is something that no one who actually writes code for a living would suggest (provided they actally knew what they were doing).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a homework question to me hence I have voted it for closing. But I thought I can still give you some tit bits that will help you.

[Generics in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) are your friends.

*Firstly use **Generics** wherever possible.*

If you know that the `List` is only going to contain `Integer`s, then declare it like

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Regarding Sum:

Just take a variable sum, iterate over it using for each loop and add all the elements by casting it to `Integer` if the type is `instanceof` `Integer`. Mind that you wont need this instanceof check if you declare it like I suggested. Assuming you only will have integers in list. Otherwise declare it like `List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();`